# How to develop flutterstudio.app using Dart or Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart web development and wondering how can I develop a site like https://flutterstudio.app/?

I am wondering how to draw the emulator like preview? Is it possible to render Flutter widgets on a canvas? Also, is it just the image or borders to make it look like mobile emulator?

I am looking for some tips to start.

Thanks.

Comment: is this web app done by flutter team or community? what does it do?

Comment: It is developed by Paul Mutisya. It allows a user to design Flutter UI using drag & drop. Please check this link https://medium.com/@pmutisya/flutter-studio-version-2-41cce10fcf3d for more information.